# Lucky Number counting

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a lucky number counter where if there is a number containing either a 6 or an 8 between the two inputs the number is lucky, but if there's both a 6 and an 8 the number is unlucky. I'm having an issue where it's double-counting numbers, like 66, 88, etc., and not calling unlucky numbers like 68, 86, etc. Please help fast :\

```
l, h = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

count = 0

for i in range(l,h+1):
    
    i = str(i)
    
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if i[j] == '6' or i[j] == '8':
            count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: ```l, h = [int(x) for x in input().split()]```? You are not asking for 2 inputs. You are askin for 1 input and splitting it into characters

Comment: Please provide some examples of actual input and why they are lucky/unlucky. For example, why are you calling 66 an unlucky number, as it has no '8'? And what do you mean exactly by "between the two inputs"? Do you mean to say that `6 8` would be unlucky and `68 1` would be as well? Or is the input always a single two-digit number?

Comment: I'm not calling 66 unluck, the issue is that it is counting 66 twice instead of a single time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys

temp1 = ""
while len(temp1) != 2:
    temp1 = input("Enter 2 digits: ")
try:
    temp2 = int(temp1)
except ValueError:
    print("You did not enter valid input")
    sys.exit(1)

lucky = False

if "6" in temp1:
    lucky = True
if "8" in temp1:
    lucky = True
if ("6" in temp1) and ("8" in temp1):
    lucky = False

print("Lucky number: "+str(lucky))
```

Comment: ```temp2 = int(temp1)``` Only ```ValueError``` can occur. Use ```except ValueError```

Comment: I want to count the number of times a lucky number, that is a number containing either a 6 or an 8, appears within an input range

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `count()` method for Strings:

```py
numbers = input().split(' ')
count = 0

for num in numbers:
    if num.count('6') > 0:
        if num.count('8') > 0:
            continue
        else:
            count += 1
    elif num.count('8') > 0:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: I want to count the number of times a lucky number, that is a number containing either a 6 or an 8, appears within an input range not if the input is lucky/unlucky

Comment: @KareemMohamed-Aly Updated the answer to allow multiple numbers in the input.

Comment: this solution is close but it still has a habit of double-counting numbers like 66

Comment: @KareemMohamed-Aly I have tested this myself and I could not recreate a double-counting scenario. Could you give me an example of the input you used to achieve double-counting?

Comment: my goal is not to double count, this solution counts numbers like 66 or 88 twice instead of once

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, probably:

```
number = ''
while len(number) != 2 or any(ch not in '0123456789' for ch in number):
    number = input('Enter a 2-digit positive integer:')

print(f'{number} is {"lucky" if ("6" in number) != ("8" in number) else "not lucky"}')

# or, if you meant to say "exactly one 6 or 8":
print(f'{number} is {"lucky" if len([ch for ch in number if ch in "68"]) == 1 else "not lucky"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

this, while not as elegant or efficient, seems to be the correct code for the implied question

```
l, h = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

count = 0

for i in range(l,h+1):
    
    i = str(i)
        
    if ('6' in i and '8' in i):
        continue 
    
    if i.count('6') > 0 or i.count('8') > 0:
        count += 1
        
print(count)
```

Comment: Your first line in this solution gives an error if you enter anything other than 2 numbers. If you desired only 2 numbers as input you should have clarified that in your original question. I would also like to point out that you used a good majority of my solution in your answer without any recognition. I'm glad I was able to help, though.